# Trouble Addressing Associate Array element returned from call in PHP

Tags: php, associative-array

I want to use an associative array element that I return from api call to compare to a string value like this:

```
<!-- Check If there are any todo items. If not skip Todo list markup. =====-->
            <?php 
            if ($todo_items['todo_id'] == '1234567')  {
                //This value indicates no todo items for person
            }
            else  {
              //markup to render todo item list
            ?>
```

This causes a " Notice: Undefined index: todo_id in /var/www/todo_client/todo.php on line 80.
I put in a var_dump($todo_items) in and results are:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'todo_id' => string '1234567' (length=7)
```

Does anyone know why I am not able to access $todo_items['todo_id']?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the API you're receiving an array of stdClasses so if you have just one item returned back, you can do something like this to test the value:

```
$result = $todo_items[0];
if ($result->todo_id == '1234567')  {/*...*/}
```

When there are (or can be) multiple items being returned you can iterate through the array (`$todo_items`) and do this test for every one of them:

```
foreach($todo_items as $item) {
   if ($result->todo_id == '1234567') {/*...*/}
}
```